# Unrecognized Quartz MS font

Tags: tesseract

I tried to generate the image with the Quartz MS font as follows.
[image]
Then use jTessBoxEditorFX to generate the box file, as follows.

```
0 26 23 97 125 0
1 169 26 189 122 0
2 209 23 279 124 0
3 305 23 370 124 0
4 391 25 461 121 0
5 481 23 551 124 0
6 571 23 641 124 0
7 665 27 731 124 0
8 753 24 822 124 0
9 842 24 912 125 0
```

The traineddata cannot be recognized normally. Is there any problem with my practice?
Whether there are similar experiences of seniors can guide me, thank you.

Comment: You'd need a lot more samples than just that small set. You may want to try the alternate program jTessBoxEditor (not FX) to see if better training images are generated.